# Как выделить клетки в таблице?

Tags: javascript, java

Подскажите, как на js выделять в имеющейся таблице клетки.

Нужны два способа: по клику мышкой и выделением блока клеток. С сохранением в переменную и отправкой этого массива в http-запросе при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Первый способ понятно, будете работать onclick, а второй способ, наверное, будете работать с mousedown: при нажатии узнать координаты, далее узнать, какие блоки находится в этой координате, получить их значения и присвоить к переменной, далее при нажатии кнопки отправить.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте будем прежде гуглить.
По поводу выделения клеток:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013902/select-cells-on-a-table-by-dragging

Формирование массива можно проводить и через какую-то функцию, которая вызывается при выделении клетки.